# LaTeX Error: Command \numberline@prefix already defined

Tags: compilation-error, bakoma

I was using TexnicsCenter for my thesis and now I changed to Bakoma. But since then I having a lot of new errors:

```
"LaTeX Error: Command \numberline@prefix already defined. Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
 ...                                              

l.2768 \newcommand*{\numberline@prefix}{}"
```

```
{%------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass{diss}
%----------------------------------------------------------
%
% ******** library settings *********
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{natdin}
%
% ******** vmargin settings *********
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setpapersize{A4}
\setmargins{3cm}%                         %linker Rand, left edge
                                         {1.5cm}%     %oberer Rand, top edge
           {15cm}%                %Textbreite, text width
           {23.42cm}%   %Texthoehe, text hight
           {14pt}%                      %Kopfzeilenhöhe, header hight
           {1cm}%         %Kopfzeilenabstand, header distance
           {0pt}%                               %Fußzeilenhoehe footer hight
           {2cm}%         %Fusszeilenabstand, footer distance         
%
% ********* Grafiken definition *******
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} % required to import graphic files
\usepackage{color} %allows to mark some entries in the tables with color
\usepackage{eso-pic} %these two are required to add the little picture on top of every page
\usepackage{everyshi} %these two are required to add the little picture on top of every page
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.7} %default:0.5 allows two big pictures on one page
%
% ********* Tabellen layout **************
\usepackage{booktabs} %design of table, has an excellent documentation
\usepackage{lscape} %to rotate the table together with the lines around the table
%
% ********* Beschriftung Layout ************
\usepackage{ccaption} %allows special formating of the captions
\captionnamefont{\bf\footnotesize\rmfamily} %font of the caption name (e.g. Figure: or Table:)
\captiontitlefont{\footnotesize\rmfamily} %font of the caption text (same as above, but not bold)
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0mm} %lowers the distace of captions to the figure
%
% ********* Header and Footer + Page style **********
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0},pdftex]{hyperref} %links in table of content im pdf zum Inhalt
\usepackage{scrpage} %header and footer using the options for the KOMA script
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\footnotesize\rmfamily} %font for the header
\renewcommand{\pnumfont}{\footnotesize\rmfamily} %font for the pagenumbers
\defpagestyle{cb}{%
(\textwidth,0pt)% sets the border line above the header
{\pagemark\hfill\headmark\hfill}% doublesided, left page
{\hfill\headmark\hfill\pagemark}% doublesided, right page
{\hfill\headmark\hfill\pagemark}%  onesided
(\textwidth,1pt)}% sets the border line below the header
%
{(\textwidth,1pt)% sets the border line above the footer
{{\it Algorithmic optimization of visual comfort and view out in office buildings}\hfill Sandra Mende}% doublesided, left page
{Sandra Mende\hfill{\it Algorithmic optimization of visual comfort and view out in office buildings}}% doublesided, right page
{Sandra Mende\hfill{\it Algorithmic optimization of visual comfort and view out in office buildings}} % one sided printing
(\textwidth,0pt)% sets the border line below the footer
}
%
% ********* Abstände inhaltsverzeichnis ************
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[]{titletoc} 
\titlecontents{section}[2.2em]{\addvspace{0.8pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{1.9em}}{\hspace*{0em}}{\titlerule*[0.675pc]{.}\contentspage}%{Abschnitt}[links]{Gesamtformatierung}{Vor dem Label}{Nach dem Label}{Abstandsfüller & Seitenzahl}[rechts]
\titlecontents{subsection}[4.7em]{}{\contentslabel{2.5em}}{\hspace*{0em}}{\titlerule*[0.675pc]{.}\contentspage}%
\titlecontents{subsubsection}[7.7em]{}{\contentslabel{3em}}{\hspace*{0em}}{\titlerule*[0.675pc]{.}\contentspage}%
\titlecontents{subsubsubsection}[11.7em]{}{\contentslabel{3.9em}}{\hspace*{-1.2em}}{\titlerule*[0.675pc]{.}\contentspage}
%
% ********* subsubsubsection definiton ************
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}} %um Buchstaben als Numerierung für Part zu haben
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{7.0em}{4.1em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{10em}{5em}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\setcounter{subsubsubsection}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsubsection}{\thesubsubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsubsection}
\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsubsection]
\titleformat{\part}{\rm\bfseries\Huge}{\thetitle}{0em}{}[]
\titleformat{\section}{\rm\bfseries\Large}{\thetitle}{2.4em}{}[]
\titleformat{\subsection}{\rm\bfseries\large}{\thetitle}{2.1em}{}[]
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\rm\bfseries\normalsize}{\thesubsubsection}{1.6em}{}[]
\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}{\rm}{\thetitle}{1.35em}{}[] %\titleformat{Überschriftenklasse}[Absatzformatierung]{Textformatierung}{Nummerierung}{Abstand zwischen Nummerierung und Überschriftentext}{Code vor der Überschrift}[Code nach der Überschrift]
\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{-3em}{6pt} %{Links}{oberhalb}{unterhalb}[rechts]
\titlespacing{\subsubsubsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus 0.2ex}{1.5ex plus 0.2ex} %{links}{oberhalb}{unterhalb}[rechts]
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}%
    {\z@}%
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}%
    {\parindent}%
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\toclevel@subsubsubsection}{4}%
\renewcommand*{\toclevel@paragraph}{5}%
\renewcommand*{\toclevel@subparagraph}{6}%
\makeatother
%
% ********* Font definiton ************
\usepackage{t1enc} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily\bfseries\boldmath} %macht alles in times
\usepackage{titlesec} \titleformat{\part}{\bf\Huge}{\thepart\quad}{0em}{} %entfernt das Wort part
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{soul}
%\usepackage{mathptmx} %mathematical fonts for use with times, some problems with pdftex%
%
% ********* Definition für Absätze ************
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\linespread{1.4}
%
%
% ********* this defines the page style for the first pages: all empty ************
\renewpagestyle{plain}%
        {(\textwidth,0pt)%
                {\hfill}{\hfill}{\hfill}%
        (\textwidth,0pt)}%
        {(\textwidth,0pt)%      
                {\hfill}{\hfill}{\hfill}%
        (\textwidth,0pt)}
%
%********** Footnotes **********
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\rule{5cm}{0.2mm} \vspace{0.3cm}} %increases the distance of footnotes from the text
\deffootnote[1em]{1em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\normalfont\thefootnotemark}} %some more formation on footnotes

%################ End Preferences, Begin Document #####################

\pagestyle{plain} % no headers or footers on the first page
\pagestyle{cb} % now we want to have headers and footers


%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\include{./content/Titlepage}
%\include{./content/Copyright} \newpage

%-preface-------------------------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{cb} \pagenumbering{roman} \setcounter{page}{1}% now we want to have headers and footers

\include{./content/Foreword} \newpage
\include{./content/Acknowledgements} \newpage

%-register------------------------------------------------------------
\tableofcontents \newpage
\listoftables \newpage
\listoffigures \newpage

%-content-------------------------------------------------------------
%-arabic number 1
\setcounter{page}{1} \pagenumbering{arabic} \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
%\include{./content/Abbreviations}
\include{./content/Chapter1}
\include{./content/Chapter2}
\include{./content/Chapter3}
\include{./content/Chapter4}

\bibliography{diss}

\end{document}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Maybe a simple solution is to switch back to your previous setup?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  The surrounding `{}` are unnecessary.  I believe the `l.2768` in the error indicates line 2768, which must refer to some other file.  It might help to remove the aux and other supporting files to create them from scratch.